# jsonp request does not show facebook data

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I am using JSON to display info from a site. The book example works which gave me a custom website to get information from worked, but when I replaced the url with Spider man's facebook page, it seems as if the data is processing, but the information does not display. Is there some crucial step that I am missing.

```
var lastReporttime = 0;
window.onload= function(){ 
  setInterval(handleRefresh,3000);
}

function updateSales(sales) {
  var salesDiv= document.getElementById("sales");
  for (var i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
    var sale = sales[i];
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = sale.category + sale.about + "spiderman";
    salesDiv.appendChild(div);
  }

  if (sales.length > 0) { lastReporttime = sales[sales.length-1].time; } 
}

function handleRefresh() {
  var url = "http://graph.facebook.com/SpiderManDVD"
          + "callback=updateSales"
          + "&lastreporttime=" + lastReporttime
          + "&random="+ (new Date()). getTime();

  var newScriptElement= document.createElement("script");
  newScriptElement.setAttribute("src", url);
  newScriptElement.setAttribute("id", "jsonp");

  var oldScriptElement= document.getElementById("jsonp");
  var head= document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  if (oldScriptElement == null) {
    head.appendChild(newScriptElement);
  } else {
    head.replaceChild(newScriptElement, oldScriptElement);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use debugger tool to see if you are getting the response of your script

Comment: the link the book gave me was  http://gumball.wickedlysmart.com/gumball/gumball.html

Comment: I am getting the response from http://graph.facebook.com/SpiderManDVD?callback=updateSales&lastreporttime=1&random=253341. Looks like response it coming from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response you received from [your book example](http://gumball.wickedlysmart.com/gumball/gumball.html) returns a JSON Array which is perfectly handled in your code.

But response from [facebook api](http://graph.facebook.com/SpiderManDVD?callback=updateSales&lastreporttime=1&random=253341) returns a JSON object which is breaking your code.

Check both the urls and update the logic inside `updateSales` to handle both JSON Array as well as JSONObject as per your use case.

Something like this

```
function updateSales(sales) {
  var salesDiv= document.getElementById('sales');

  // Check if sales is array or not (One of the crude ways, ofcourse not best but may work for you)
  if (typeof sales.length == 'undefined') {
    sales = [sales];
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < sales.length; i++) {
    var sale = sales[i];
    var div = document.createElement("div");

    div.innerHTML = sale.category + sale.about + "spiderman";
    salesDiv.appendChild(div);
  }

  if (sales.length > 0) { 
    lastReporttime = sales[sales.length-1].time; 
  }
}
```